# Generate bib file using latexmk (potentially add_cus_dep)

Tags: biblatex, biber, latexmk

I need to do some pre-processing to a bib file that is generated by a reference manager before passing it to biblatex. So I have created a script to this and tried to automate the call to this script with latexmk.

Since `add_cus_dep` only handles extensions and not whole file names, I have tried something like this:

- `thesis.bibinput` is my unprocessed source file
- I want to generate `thesis.bib`

I have added the following fragment to `latexmkrc`:

```
add_cus_dep('bibinput', 'bib', 1, 'bibfix');
sub bibfix {
    system("bibfix -x bibfix_transform.py \"$_[0]\" thesis.bib");
}
```

However, when compiling the document, the custom step is not called and the bib file is not generated.

I am using biblatex with biber and latexmk correctly outputs that biber didn't find the input file:

```
Biber error: [244] Utils.pm:180> ERROR - Cannot find 'thesis.bib'!
Latexmk: Biber did't find bib file [thesis.bib]
Latexmk: Summary of warnings:
  Latex failed to resolve 36 citation(s)
```

How can I convince latexmk to generate my bib file?

Comment: Just wondering, is there supposed to be a space between - and x in the above?

Comment: oops, no. But the command should fail in this case and latexmk would have to raise the error. Even this didn't happen.

Comment: `$_[0]` is missing the extension, but that's not your problem I guess.   Can you produce a minimal complete example?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following code in the `rc` file will work for you

```
system("bibfix -x bibfix_transform.py thesis.bibinput thesis.bib");
```

By the way, I don't think the custom dependency rule could do this job in current `latexmk`, unless you change the source code of `latexmk`, i.e., `latexmk.pl`.

I would recommend you to use `make`, or other tools.